# CC3200. compiler warnings when use freertos with math.h

Tags: gcc, freertos, math.h

I have to use some functions from math library on a CC3200 Project. This project has to use freertos and the IDE is CCS. With this combination, the compiler show these warnings:

```
/ymath.h", line 550: warning #225-D: function "_ftoi" declared implicitly
/ymath.h", line 592: warning #225-D: function "_hi" declared implicitly
/ymath.h", line 594: warning #225-D: function "_lo" declared implicitly
/ymath.h", line 604: warning #225-D: function "_lo" declared implicitly
```

To reproduce the problem, we have to import to CCS the "freertos_demo" project from CC3200SDK_X.X.X and in the main.c file add the include directive: `#include <math.h>` only that.
if we compile the project we get the warnings.

Thanks in advance.
JM

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this has to do with FreeRTOS as the functions that are generating the warnings are not used in the FreeRTOS Cortex-M4 port.  Perhaps they are only used in demo code, in which case, can't you just include the necessary header files in the demo source files (this won't effect FreeRTOS at all)?  Where did you get the demo from?  It's not [a project from the FreeRTOS distribution](http://www.freertos.org/a00090.html).